# How to access Flash ExternalInterface from QWebView?

Tags: flash, qt, externalinterface, qtwebkit, qwebview

Is it possible to access Flash's ExternalInterface from `QWebView`? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try accessing it via executing JavaScript in the page.

To run JavaScript on the page use [`QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript), for example:

```
QWebView* webView;
// ...
QString jsQuery("document.getElementById(\"flashobj\").flashFunc(1);");
QVariant result = webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(jsQuery);
```

Note: I've not tested this code, or even tried accessing Flash before via QtWebKit so this may not work for Flash, although it does work for JavaScript objects.